# Not fetching any events using Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Using This code for getting event:-

```
new Request(session,"/{event-id}",null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {
           public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
           System.out.println("Result: " + response.toString());
         }
      }).executeAsync();
   }
});
```

Permission :---

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes","user_events","read_stream"));
```

And it gave me error :----

```
I/System.out﹕ Result: {Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {event-id}}, isFromCache:false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explains it

> (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {event-id}

```
new Request(session,"/{event-id}",null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback()
```

There should be an actual event ID or at least a variable that holds the value of an event ID.

Comment: Can we get list of all events held in a particular location?